# Empty content in output out from while cycle

Tags: c++

I want to load data from .txt file to variable and working with them (like calculate). When I open data, I can read them, but I don´t know to work with data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    fstream newfile;
    string file;

    newfile.open("zadanie.txt", ios::in);
    if (newfile.is_open()) {   

        while (getline(newfile, file)) { 
            cout << file << "\n"; //I GET OUTPUT CORRECTLY
        }

        newfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Error. \n";

    cout << file << "\n"; //HERE IS PROBLEM. OUTPUT IS EMPTY


    return 0;
}
```

I tried global variable, but it not solved. What should I do to correct it? Thanks

Comment: This might be putting the cart before the horse. How do you want to store the lines of the file? You should first define that. A reasonable choice would be `std::vector<std::string>`. Only then should you decide how to fill the variable you defined.

Comment: each line you read replaces the previous content of `file`.  You need to have a strategy on how to handle those lines further down the line

Comment: If `newfile` fails to open, your `file` string will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "PROBLEM" in the comment is not a problem. `file` never contains more than a single from the file. The last call to `getline` will not read a line because there is nothing left in the file when you reach its end. So when you call

```
std::cout << file;
```

after that loop, it is to be expected that `file` is empty. If you want to use the lines later you should store them somewhere, eg in a `std::vector<std::string>>` :

```
int main()
{
    fstream newfile;
    std::vector<std::string> data;          // vector to hold all lines

    newfile.open("zadanie.txt", ios::in);
    if (newfile.is_open()) {   
        string line;                        // better name (file->line)
        while (getline(newfile, line)) { 
            cout << line << "\n";
            data.push_back(line);            // add the line to data
        }    
        newfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Error. \n";

    for (const auto& l : data) std::cout << l << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `file` by `line`.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam yeah I confused myself by renaming the variable and created a mess. Thx, fixed now